# Where is Lydia's new home with the Blades?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Where is Lydia's new home? I have the Breezehome and I'm well into the game. I remember a while ago when we were in Riverwood, she joined the Blades and they said when she was done with me, she was invited to go with them.

Where are the Blades located? I let her go in Whiterun while she was sitting down inside the Breezehome and she left. Walking out of Whiterun, I followed her for a while and she just walks back and forth across the whole map.

Where is she trying to go?

Comment: if your talking about Lydia have you tried Skyruler temple, where the Blade are actually based? quite sure Blades recruits go there though i never heard of them being recruited by any other way that you doing it yourself

Answer (score 2):

The Blades are located at [Sky Haven Temple](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Sky_Haven_Temple). Check out this link for information on [Rebuilding the Blades](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Rebuilding_the_Blades). Once a follower joins the Blades they will permanently be relocated to this place. If they die you cannot replace the follower (i.e. another recruit cannot join the Blades in their place).